# What's the probability that their weight will be equal to each other?

Tags: probability

An electronic weighning measures

- $1$kg more than its weight with the probability of $20\%$
- $1$kg less than its weight with the probability of $30\%$
- correctly with the probability of $50\%$

Tim's and John's initial weights are $80$ and $81$. Consider Tim and John weighted respectively. What's the probability that their weight will be equal to each other?

We need to note that the probability will be somewhere between $0$ and $1$. However, it will never be greater than $1$ and equal to $0$. On the condition that Tim weights $80$, John's weight should be measured as $80$. Thereby, we will pick up the probabilities $50\%$ and $30\%$. Now on the condition that Tim weights $81$, John's weight should be measured as $81$. Hence, we will pick up the probabilities $20\%$ and $50\%$ respectively. Finally,

$$P(X)=1 - \biggr [(0.5+0.3)-(0.2+0.5)\biggr ]$$

$$P (X) = 0.9 = 90\%$$

Which gives me the wrong answer. Could you take a look?

Regards!

Comment: "Consider Tim and John weighted respectively." Are Tim and John initial weight the same?

Comment: @ClarkMakmur Sorry, forgot to add! Their weights initial weights are $80$ and $81$ respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weight reading for Tim is as follows:
$$P(Tim =79) = \frac{30}{100}$$
$$P(Tim =80) = \frac{50}{100}$$
$$P(Tim =81) = \frac{20}{100}$$
The weight reading for John is as follows:
$$P(John =80) = \frac{30}{100}$$
$$P(John =81) = \frac{50}{100}$$
$$P(John =82) = \frac{20}{100}$$
So, probability Tim weight equal to John weight ($\cup$ means AND)
$$P(X) = P(Tim =80 \cup John = 80) + P(Tim =81 \cup John=81)$$
We know that the Tim and John weight are independent which means. (An event A and B are independent so:)
$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) * P(B)$$
So,
 $$P(Tim =80 \cup John = 80) =P(Tim=80) * P(John=80)$$

$$P(Tim =80 \cup John = 80) =\frac{50}{100} * \frac{30}{100}=0.15$$
The other one
$$P(Tim =81 \cup John=81)=P(Tim=81) * P(John=81)$$

$$P(Tim =81 \cup John=81)=\frac{20}{100}*\frac{50}{100}=0.1$$
So,

$$P(X) = P(Tim =80 \cup John = 80) + P(Tim =81 \cup John=81)=0.25$$

Comment: Did I sum the probabilities up instead of multiplying?

Answer (score 1):

Let $T,B$ be the displayed weights of Tim and Bill, respectively.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;P(T=B)
&=P(T=B=80)+P(T=B=81)\\[4pt]
&=P(T=80)P(B=80)+P(T=81)P(B=81)\\[4pt]
&=(.50)(.30)+(.20)(.50)\\[4pt]
&=.25
\end{align*}